# how add notification sound in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

In my android application, I want to notify the user with a sound without showing the notification.

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 shownotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
public void shownotification(String message){
    PendingIntent p1=PendingIntent.getActivities(this,0, new Intent[]{new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)}, 0);
    Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(p1)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notification);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a Uri for your sound

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

and add it to your notification

```
.setSound(alarmSound)
```

and clear the notification you created. `notificationManager.cancelAll();`

So your code looks like this.

```
public void shownotification(String message){
 Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
 PendingIntent p1=PendingIntent.getActivities(this,0, new Intent[]{new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)}, 0);
 Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .setContentTitle("Notification")
        .setContentText(message)
        .setContentIntent(p1)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(alarmSound)
        .build();
 NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 notificationManager.notify(0,notification);
 notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

}

Then clear the notification you created.

Comment: Did it produce sound?

Comment: You are creating a notification and cancelling that so that it produces sound and will not display notification on user point of view